# How to sum value of a property in an array of objects with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, typescript

So I  am getting an array of **results** from a nodejs api to my angular app and it looks like this

```
    [
      {
        "session": "2019/2020",
        "harmattan": [
          {
            "course_code": "CSC104",
            "title": "Object Oriented Programming",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:11:54.557Z",
              "_id": "5fca1a8daac49e44a40a80e6",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC105",
            "title": "Problem Solving",
            "unit": 3,
            "status": "R",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:11:54.557Z",
              "_id": "5fca1aaaaac49e44a40a8105",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          }
        ],
        "rain": [
          {
            "course_code": "CSC101",
            "title": "Modelling and Simulation",
            "unit": 3,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1cd729eca3320c6245cc",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC102",
            "title": "Introduction to Computer Science",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1d2829eca3320c6245eb",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC103",
            "title": "Data Structures",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "E",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1d5429eca3320c62460a",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "session": "2020/2021",
        "harmattan": [
          {
            "course_code": "CSC104",
            "title": "Object Oriented Programming",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:11:54.557Z",
              "_id": "5fca1a8daac49e44a40a80e6",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC105",
            "title": "Problem Solving",
            "unit": 3,
            "status": "R",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:11:54.557Z",
              "_id": "5fca1aaaaac49e44a40a8105",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          }
        ],
        "rain": [
          {
            "course_code": "CSC101",
            "title": "Modelling and Simulation",
            "unit": 3,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1cd729eca3320c6245cc",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC102",
            "title": "Introduction to Computer Science",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "C",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1d2829eca3320c6245eb",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          },
          {
            "course_code": "CSC103",
            "title": "Data Structures",
            "unit": 2,
            "status": "E",
            "result": {
              "updatedAt": "2020-12-04T11:25:38.901Z",
              "_id": "5fca1d5429eca3320c62460a",
              "matric_no": "U19CYS1076",
              "ca": 3,
              "exam": 48,
              "total": 51,
              "point": 3,
              "grade": "C"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Now, what i intend to achieve on my frontend is this:

1. Display the Results for every available sessions, Harmattan Semester comes first, followed by Rain Semester.
2. I want to sum all the unit of each courses together (TNU) for each semester in session.
3. I want to sum the points of each courses together (TCP) for each semester in a session
4. Then I want the result of No. 3 (total points) to be divided by No. 2 (total units) to give me GPA.
5. The Result of No. 3 and No. 4 will now be kept and added to other semester results accordingly to give the cummulative value i.e CTNU, CTCP, CGPA. That is, total units for Harmattan semester 2019/2020 will be added to Rain semester 2019/2020 and other sessions accordingly. Same with the grade points.

Let me show you how my frontend code looks for now

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
<div *ngIf="result.harmattan.length > 0">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2">PROGRAM: {{userData?.department | uppercase}}</th>
                <th>ACADEMIC YEAR: {{result.session}}</th>
                <th colspan="2">SEMESTER: HARMATTAN</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="thead-light">
                <th>COURSE CODE</th>
                <th>COURSE NAME</th>
                <th>UNIT</th>
                <th>GRADE</th>
                <th>CREDIT POINT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr *ngFor="let first of result.harmattan" >
              <td>{{first.course_code}}</td>
              <td>{{first.title}}</td>
              <td>{{first.unit}}</td>
              <td>{{first.result.grade}}</td>
              <td>{{first.result.point * first.unit}}</td>
            </tr>
            <p>Total Units: **value**</p>
            <p>Total Points: **value**</p>
            <p>GPA: **value**</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Units: **value**</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Points: **value**</p>
            <pCumulative GPA: **value**</p>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="result.rain.length > 0">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2">PROGRAM: {{userData?.department | uppercase}}</th>
                <th>ACADEMIC YEAR: {{result.session}}</th>
                <th colspan="2">SEMESTER: RAIN</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="thead-light">
                <th>COURSE CODE</th>
                <th>COURSE NAME</th>
                <th>UNIT</th>
                <th>GRADE</th>
                <th>CREDIT POINT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr *ngFor="let second of result.rain">
              <td>{{second.course_code}}</td>
              <td>{{second.title}}</td>
              <td>{{second.unit}}</td>
              <td>{{second.result.grade}}</td>
              <td>{{second.result.point * second.unit}}</td>
            </tr>
            <p>Total Units: **value**</p>
            <p>Total Points: **value**</p>
            <p>GPA: **value**</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Units: **value**</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Points: **value**</p>
            <pCumulative GPA: **value**</p>

          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
```

Now let me show you a graphical representation of what I'm talking about
[graphical output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aujab.jpg)

**Keys**

- TNU: Total number of units
- TCP: Total Credit Points
- GPA: Grade Point Average
- CTNU: Cummulative Total Number of units
- CTCP: Cummulative Total Credit Points
- CGPA: Cummulative Grade Point Average

Below of is what i have on my typescript file, if it's needed.

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.resultService.getResults()
        .subscribe(responseData => {
          this.results = responseData.results;
          console.log(this.results);
          this.userData = responseData.userData;
        });
      }
```

I'll be on the comments section.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using map and reduce to sum the values of interest?

Comment: Yes it didn't work. I guess i wasn't using it the right way.

Comment: It might be helpful to show what you tried and explain what did not work as expected.  (You might in fact not use map, depending on how you collect the information.)  Are you able to use reduce to sum a list?  For example `[1,2,3].reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best solution but try this:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of resultData; let i = index">
<div *ngIf="result.harmattan.length > 0">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <!-- <th colspan="2">PROGRAM: {{userData?.department | uppercase}}</th> -->
                <th>ACADEMIC YEAR: {{result.session}}</th>
                <th colspan="2">SEMESTER: HARMATTAN</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="thead-light">
                <th>COURSE CODE</th>
                <th>COURSE NAME</th>
                <th>UNIT</th>
                <th>GRADE</th>
                <th>CREDIT POINT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr *ngFor="let first of result.harmattan" >
              <td>{{first.course_code}}</td>
              <td>{{first.title}}</td>
              <td>{{first.unit}}</td>
              <td>{{first.result.grade}}</td>
              <td>{{first.result.point * first.unit}}</td>
            </tr>
            <p>Total Units: {{ totalUnits(result.harmattan) }}</p>
            <p>Total Points: {{ totalPoints(result.harmattan) }}</p>
            <p>GPA: {{ totalGPA(result.harmattan) }}</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Units: {{cumulativeUnits(result.harmattan, i, 'harmattan')}}</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Points: {{cumulativePoints(result.harmattan, i, 'harmattan')}}</p>
            <p> Cumulative GPA: {{cumulativeGPA(result.harmattan, i, 'harmattan')}}</p>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div *ngIf="result.rain.length > 0">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <!-- <th colspan="2">PROGRAM: {{userData?.department | uppercase}}</th> -->
                  <th>ACADEMIC YEAR: {{result.session}}</th>
                  <th colspan="2">SEMESTER: RAIN</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="thead-light">
                  <th>COURSE CODE</th>
                  <th>COURSE NAME</th>
                  <th>UNIT</th>
                  <th>GRADE</th>
                  <th>CREDIT POINT</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tr *ngFor="let second of result.rain">
                <td>{{second.course_code}}</td>
                <td>{{second.title}}</td>
                <td>{{second.unit}}</td>
                <td>{{second.result.grade}}</td>
                <td>{{second.result.point * second.unit}}</td>
              </tr>
              <p>Total Units: {{ totalUnits(result.rain) }}</p>
            <p>Total Points: {{ totalPoints(result.rain) }}</p>
            <p>GPA: {{ totalGPA(result.rain) }}</p>
            <p>Cumulative Total Units: {{cumulativeUnits(result.rain, i, 'rain')}}</p>
              <p>Cumulative Total Points: {{cumulativePoints(result.rain, i, 'rain')}}</p>
              <p>Cumulative GPA: {{cumulativeGPA(result.rain, i, 'rain')}}</p>
  
            </table>
          </div>
```

Ts file :

```
cumulativeUnits(result, session, semester){
let tnu = 0
var tnuHarmattan = 0;
let thisSemester = 0;
if(session == 0){
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
    }
    return tnuHarmattan;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
    }
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].rain){
      tnu += item.unit;
    }
    return tnuHarmattan + tnu;
  }
}
else{
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i < session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        tnu += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of result){
        thisSemester += item.unit;
      }
    }
    return tnuHarmattan + tnu + thisSemester;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i <= session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        tnu += item.unit;
      }
    }
    return tnuHarmattan + tnu;
  }
  
}
```

}

```
cumulativePoints(result, session, semester){
let gpSemester = 0;
let guyCPRain = 0;
let guyCPharmattan = 0;
if(session == 0){
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
    }
    return guyCPharmattan;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
    }
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].rain){
      guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
    }
    return guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain;
  }
}
else{
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i < session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
      for(let item of result){
        gpSemester +=  (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
    }
    return guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain + gpSemester;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i <= session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
    }
    return guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain;
  }
  
}
```

}

```
cumulativeGPA(result, session, semester){
let tnu = 0
var tnuHarmattan = 0;
let thisSemester = 0;
let guyCPRain = 0;
let guyCPharmattan = 0;
let gpSemester = 0;
if(session == 0){
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
    }
    return guyCPharmattan / tnuHarmattan;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].harmattan){
      guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
    }
    for(let item of this.resultData[0].rain){
      guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
      tnu += item.unit;
    }
    return ((guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain) / (tnuHarmattan + tnu)).toFixed(2);
  }
}
else{
  if (semester == 'harmattan'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i < session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
        tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
        tnu += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of result){
        thisSemester += item.unit;
        gpSemester +=  (item.result.point * item.unit);
      }
    }
    return ((guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain + gpSemester) / (tnuHarmattan + tnu + thisSemester)).toFixed(2);;
  }
  else if (semester == 'rain'){
    for(let i:number = 0; i <= session; i++){
  
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].harmattan){
        guyCPharmattan += (item.result.point * item.unit);
        tnuHarmattan += item.unit;
      }
      for(let item of this.resultData[i].rain){
        guyCPRain += (item.result.point * item.unit);
        tnu += item.unit;
      }
    }
    return ((guyCPharmattan + guyCPRain) / (tnuHarmattan + tnu)).toFixed(2);
  }
  
}
```

}